# lost connection to device when using flutter maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps

I am currently showing map in my screen using google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.6 package, but whenever I try to restart my code or reload multiple times the map screen (re-show maps screen continuously) it will get lost connection to device without any error log. It's always fine whenever load the screen for the first time, but not when 4 times or 5 times reload. Is there a way to solve this ? I have checked the configuration api key in android manifest, appdelegete.swift. Also I have done adding permission for location access inside info.plist and android manifest